# SQL Query to Extract Timestamp Difference

Tags: sql, ms-access, timestamp

I have been delegated a task on a dataset that has been pre-extracted from another data source(s) and I currently only have Access available to query this data (Excel for basic data analysis as less than row limit at the moment). Essentially, I have three relevant fields:

FK_ID = arbitrary number associated with a transaction

CD = code associated with status of transaction (assume only BEGIN and END are the values)

TIMESTAMP = timestamp of transaction

Now a simplified example of this data set:

```
FK_ID           CD                 TIMESTAMP
000012          END                2012-01-02-14.27.59.133612
000012          BEGIN              2012-01-02-14.27.57.176631
000015          END                2011-12-12-14.27.59.133612
000015          BEGIN              2011-12-11-14.27.59.133612
000019          END                2011-11-10-14.27.59.133612
000019          BEGIN              2011-11-09-14.27.59.133612
000019          END                2011-11-08-14.27.59.133612
000019          BEGIN              2011-11-07-14.27.59.133612
```

As you can see, it's not very complicated, the problem is I need to calculate the timestamp difference between the BEGIN and END codes for each unique FK_ID and then create a column to tally that difference, also accounting for the fact that some FK_IDs have multiple timestamps BEGIN/END pairs associated with them.

Now I have been authorized to ignore cases where more than a pair exists (by ignore, I mean only count that initial pair), but it is not preferable.

I need to get these differences though to determine a total average time to determine if that time is within our goals approximately.

What's the best query to go about getting this timestamp difference for each FK_ID pair or other automated means you'd suggest?

I do understand SQL and am proficient enough in C#, but the time frame and other factors are wreaking havoc on my ability to break down this problem logically.

Comment: What this comes from I don't know, I only had access to a spreadsheet that I had to import into Access (which is Jet Engine I believe). I do not have access to the source databases and due to our infrastructure, access cannot be gotten and queries cannot be run except as mainframe jobs.

Comment: Can you ensure that there will be no overlaps in the timestamps for the same fk_id. In other words, every START is followed by STOP and not another START.

Comment: The IDs are very atomic to specific transactions. In reality they are about 40 characters long and should meet the criteria you mentioned. Timestamps will not overlap for the same ids.

Comment: Worthwhile to note that if this is something not well-suited to a query, then best ways to approach it as a spreadsheet would be recommended, as I originally got the data as an Excel file that I only later ported into Access for local query-work. Barely room for it in Excel though.

Comment: I think Access/Excel aren't going to be up to this without some VBA.  (and you might try the superuser stackexchange site for that)  If you can take this into SQL Server (sqlexpress is fine) or some other featureful RDBMS, you can number the rows and easily throw out any where there's more than one pair per fk, if not accurately pair them up and consider all intervals.  But I don't know for sure that you can just subtract one timestamp from another to get an interval (or that this would import into sql server with data type of timestamp) anyone have predictions/promises on that?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the table name is TABLE1, in Access I would do something like:

```
SELECT Table1.FK_ID, DateDiff("s",[TABLE1].[TIMESTAMP],[END_QUERY].[TIMESTAMP]) AS DifferenceInSeconds
FROM Table1 

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT Table1.FK_ID, Table1.CD, Table1.TIMESTAMP
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.CD)="END"))
ORDER BY Table1.FK_ID, Table1.CD) AS END_QUERY 


ON Table1.FK_ID = END_QUERY.FK_ID
WHERE (((Table1.CD)="BEGIN"))
ORDER BY Table1.FK_ID, Table1.CD;
```

Basically, get all the BEGIN and END on two subqueries and get the difference between the queries (in seconds -- you didn't mention this part). The one issue you'll encounter is one a trasaction has multiple entries. You could do a GROUP BY to get the very first BEGIN and the very last END, but they may be some discrepancies.

I hope this helps you a little.

Comment: +1 for posting something that works with JET, since it can't join on constant values.